# NullPointerException usando WindowsBuilder y JFrame

Tags: java, eclipse

Estoy tratando de hacer un ejercicio para aprender a usar WindowsBuilder y JFrame y cuando hago click en el botón para hacer los cálculos, me sale el error:

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
>     at GUI$2.actionPerformed(GUI.java:109)  at
>   javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)    at
>   javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)    at
>   javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)    at
>   javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)     at
>   javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown
>   Source)   at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)     at
>   javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown
>   Source)   at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown
>   Source)   at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
>     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
>     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown
>   Source)   at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
>     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)

El código entero es:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JButton;

import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.text.NumberFormat;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.border.TitledBorder;
import javax.swing.JRadioButton;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import java.awt.Color;
import javax.swing.JCheckBox;


public class GUI extends JFrame {

    private JPanel contentPane;
    private JTextField txtNumeroOrigen;
    private JTextField txtNumeroDestino;
    private JTextField txtDuracion;
    private JTextField txtPrecio;
    private JCheckBox checkboxProvincial;
    private JCheckBox checkboxLocal;
    private JCheckBox checkboxFranja1;
    private JCheckBox checkboxFranja2;
    private JCheckBox checkboxFranja3;
    Centralita callcenter = new Centralita();

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    GUI frame = new GUI();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the frame.
     */
    public GUI() {
        setResizable(false);
        setTitle("Call Center");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 450, 190);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new TitledBorder(UIManager.getBorder("TitledBorder.border"), "Calcular Llamadas", TitledBorder.LEADING, TitledBorder.TOP, null, new Color(0, 0, 0)));
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        contentPane.setLayout(null);

        JLabel lblTipo = new JLabel("Tipo:");
        lblTipo.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 11));
        lblTipo.setBounds(6, 30, 46, 14);
        contentPane.add(lblTipo);

        JLabel lblFraja = new JLabel("Fraja:");
        lblFraja.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 11));
        lblFraja.setBounds(6, 107, 46, 14);
        contentPane.add(lblFraja);

        JLabel lblNmeroOrigen = new JLabel("N\u00FAmero Origen");
        lblNmeroOrigen.setBounds(128, 30, 108, 14);
        contentPane.add(lblNmeroOrigen);

        JLabel lblNmeroDestino = new JLabel("N\u00FAmero Destino");
        lblNmeroDestino.setBounds(128, 55, 108, 14);
        contentPane.add(lblNmeroDestino);

        JLabel lblDuracion = new JLabel("Duraci\u00F3n");
        lblDuracion.setBounds(128, 81, 108, 14);
        contentPane.add(lblDuracion);

        txtNumeroOrigen = new JTextField();
        txtNumeroOrigen.setBounds(246, 30, 130, 20);
        contentPane.add(txtNumeroOrigen);
        txtNumeroOrigen.setColumns(10);

        txtNumeroDestino = new JTextField();
        txtNumeroDestino.setBounds(246, 55, 130, 20);
        contentPane.add(txtNumeroDestino);
        txtNumeroDestino.setColumns(10);

        txtDuracion = new JTextField();
        txtDuracion.setBounds(246, 81, 130, 20);
        contentPane.add(txtDuracion);
        txtDuracion.setColumns(10);

        JButton btnCalcular = new JButton("Calcular");
        btnCalcular.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                // Si es Llamada Local
                if (checkboxLocal.isSelected())
                {
                    LlamadaLocal callLocal = new LlamadaLocal (txtNumeroOrigen.getText(), txtNumeroDestino.getText(), Integer.parseInt(txtDuracion.getText()));
                    callcenter.registrarLlamada(callLocal);
                    refrescarPrecio(callcenter.getTotalFacturado());
                }

                // Si es Llamada Provincial y Franja 1
                else if (checkboxProvincial.isSelected() && checkboxFranja1.isSelected())
                {
                    LlamadaProvincial callProvincial = new LlamadaProvincial (txtNumeroOrigen.getText(), txtNumeroDestino.getText(), Integer.parseInt(txtDuracion.getText()), 1);
                    callcenter.registrarLlamada(callProvincial);
                    refrescarPrecio(callcenter.getTotalFacturado());
                }

                // Si es Llamada Provincial y Franja 2
                else if (checkboxProvincial.isSelected() && checkboxFranja2.isSelected())
                {
                    LlamadaProvincial callProvincial = new LlamadaProvincial (txtNumeroOrigen.getText(), txtNumeroDestino.getText(), Integer.parseInt(txtDuracion.getText()), 2);
                    callcenter.registrarLlamada(callProvincial);
                    refrescarPrecio(callcenter.getTotalFacturado());
                }

                // Si es Llamada Provincial y Franja 3
                else if (checkboxProvincial.isSelected() && checkboxFranja3.isSelected())
                {
                    LlamadaProvincial callProvincial = new LlamadaProvincial (txtNumeroOrigen.getText(), txtNumeroDestino.getText(), Integer.parseInt(txtDuracion.getText()), 3);
                    callcenter.registrarLlamada(callProvincial);
                    refrescarPrecio(callcenter.getTotalFacturado());
                }

                // Si nada esta seleccionado
                else
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Debe seleccionar el tipo de llamada y la franja.");
            }
        });

        btnCalcular.setBounds(147, 128, 89, 23);
        contentPane.add(btnCalcular);

        JButton btnLimpiar = new JButton("Limpiar");
        btnLimpiar.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                txtNumeroOrigen.setText("");
                txtNumeroDestino.setText("");
                txtDuracion.setText("");
                txtPrecio.setText("");
                checkboxProvincial.setSelected(false);
                checkboxLocal.setSelected(false);
                checkboxFranja1.setSelected(false);
                checkboxFranja2.setSelected(false);
                checkboxFranja3.setSelected(false);
            }
        });
        btnLimpiar.setBounds(246, 128, 89, 23);
        contentPane.add(btnLimpiar);

        txtPrecio = new JTextField();
        txtPrecio.setForeground(Color.RED);
        txtPrecio.setEditable(false);
        txtPrecio.setBounds(345, 129, 86, 20);
        contentPane.add(txtPrecio);
        txtPrecio.setColumns(10);

        JLabel lblPrecio = new JLabel("Precio:");
        lblPrecio.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 11));
        lblPrecio.setBounds(385, 107, 46, 14);
        contentPane.add(lblPrecio);

        JCheckBox checkboxProvincial = new JCheckBox("Provincial");
        checkboxProvincial.setBounds(6, 51, 97, 23);
        contentPane.add(checkboxProvincial);

        JCheckBox checkboxLocal = new JCheckBox("Local");
        checkboxLocal.setBounds(6, 77, 97, 23);
        contentPane.add(checkboxLocal);

        JCheckBox checkboxFranja1 = new JCheckBox("1");
        checkboxFranja1.setBounds(6, 128, 39, 23);
        contentPane.add(checkboxFranja1);

        JCheckBox checkboxFranja2 = new JCheckBox("2");
        checkboxFranja2.setBounds(47, 128, 39, 23);
        contentPane.add(checkboxFranja2);

        JCheckBox checkboxFranja3 = new JCheckBox("3");
        checkboxFranja3.setBounds(88, 128, 46, 23);
        contentPane.add(checkboxFranja3);
    }

    public void refrescarPrecio(double precio)
    {
        DecimalFormat df = (DecimalFormat)NumberFormat.getInstance();
        df.applyPattern("$ ###,###.##");

        String Precio = "";
        Precio = df.format(Precio);
        txtPrecio.setText(Precio);
    }
}
```

Foto del programa:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿A qué puntero se refiere el error? No entiendo cuál es el problema.

Comment: El error indica: `GUI.java:109`. ¿Cual es la sentencia en la línea 109?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException at GUI$2.actionPerformed(**GUI.java:109**) at

Parece que el error viene de esta línea:

```
if (checkboxLocal.isSelected()) // checkboxLocal es "null"
```

El problema es que has duplicado la definición de las variables de tus controles. Para varias de entre ellas (incluyendo `checkboxLocal`), tienes una versión local y otra global. Y las que están inicializadas correctamente son las locales. Pero las que necesitas son las globales, las cuales nunca han sido inicializadas, por lo que recibes el error.

En concreto, esta parte de tu código:

```
JCheckBox checkboxProvincial = new JCheckBox("Provincial"); // local
checkboxProvincial.setBounds(6, 51, 97, 23);
contentPane.add(checkboxProvincial);

JCheckBox checkboxLocal = new JCheckBox("Local"); // local
checkboxLocal.setBounds(6, 77, 97, 23);
contentPane.add(checkboxLocal);

JCheckBox checkboxFranja1 = new JCheckBox("1"); // local
checkboxFranja1.setBounds(6, 128, 39, 23);
contentPane.add(checkboxFranja1);

JCheckBox checkboxFranja2 = new JCheckBox("2"); // local
checkboxFranja2.setBounds(47, 128, 39, 23);
contentPane.add(checkboxFranja2);

JCheckBox checkboxFranja3 = new JCheckBox("3"); // local
checkboxFranja3.setBounds(88, 128, 46, 23);
contentPane.add(checkboxFranja3);
```

... debería cambiarse a (nota el uso de las globales):

```
this.checkboxProvincial = new JCheckBox("Provincial"); // global
checkboxProvincial.setBounds(6, 51, 97, 23);
contentPane.add(checkboxProvincial);

this.checkboxLocal = new JCheckBox("Local"); // global
checkboxLocal.setBounds(6, 77, 97, 23);
contentPane.add(checkboxLocal);

this.checkboxFranja1 = new JCheckBox("1"); // global
checkboxFranja1.setBounds(6, 128, 39, 23);
contentPane.add(checkboxFranja1);

this.checkboxFranja2 = new JCheckBox("2"); // global
checkboxFranja2.setBounds(47, 128, 39, 23);
contentPane.add(checkboxFranja2);

this.checkboxFranja3 = new JCheckBox("3"); // global
checkboxFranja3.setBounds(88, 128, 46, 23);
contentPane.add(checkboxFranja3);
```

Tal vez hay otros problemas, pero ese es un comienzo.

Comment: Hola, muchas gracias hermano, el problema ha sido solucionado. Me gustaría saber un poco mas, por qué hay que ponerle "this."?. Qué es lo correcto, declararlo arriba como yo lo hice, o dejarlo declarado abajo como yo lo tenía?.

Answer (score 0):

Tu problema es que nunca has inicializado la variable `checkboxLocal` o por lo menos no se vé en el código que nos has puesto, por eso te salta `NullPointerException` cuando llamas a su método `checkboxLocal.isSelected()` en la fila 109.